# Should we allow questions asking opinions about what type of shot is in a given screenshot?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I came across this question in the Close votes review queue — [Open vs closed shot](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70278/open-vs-closed-shot).

> Would you classify this image from Miss Peregrine’s Home for Peculiar Children as an open frame or a closed frame? Why?
>
> [image]

It received a close vote as opinion-based because it was asking for opinions on what type of shot was used in the given screenshot. However, [it was left open in the review queue by two other users, one of whom was a community moderator](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/close/94728), taking it out of the review queue.

I agree with the initial close voter and voted to close the question as opinion-based. I agree that the question invites opinions on what types of shot is used in the screenshot. Also, I don't think this type of question is suitable for this site, which is focused on questions about movies and TV shows from the perspective of movie and television enthusiasts (the audience), not on filmmaking (identifying types of shots).

I also believe that the question does not fit the guidelines of the help center on what types of questions are [allowed](/help/on-topic) and [not allowed](/help/dont-ask) here.

> **Please note that the following subjects are considered *off-topic* here:**
>
> > - Opinions about […] a movie or TV show

> **To prevent your question from being flagged [and possibly removed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/deleted-questions), *avoid* asking subjective questions where …**
> […]
> **Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be *constructive***. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
> […]
>
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions

Leaving this question open could invite other opinion-based, filmmaking questions that also ask, "Would you classify this screenshot from [insert movie or TV show here] as an X type of shot or as a Y type of shot? Why?"

##### Should we allow questions asking opinions about what type of shot is in a given screenshot?

Comment: It looks like a good example of a good [`terminology`](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and [`film-techniques`](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film-techniques) question. It received a good-quality non-subjective answer 7 years ago, and anyone reading that answer will come away with a better understanding of terminology and how the related techniques are used, with references for further reading. Good job well done, asker and answerer. I don't understand where the problem is?

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 I’m not talking about the answer here, but the question, so let’s focus on the question. Could you please elaborate on your reasoning for why the question (*not the answer*) is not opinion-based and post it as an answer to this meta post so that the community can vote on it?